# System of $4$ bilinear equations in $4$ unknowns

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Given $n_1, n_2, n_3, n_4$, is it possible to find the values for $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ from the equations below?

$$ \begin{aligned} a b = n_1 \\ b c = n_2 \\ c d = n_3 \\ d a = n_4 \end{aligned} $$

Comment: There is no solution.

Comment: First of all you need that $n_1n_3=n_2n_4$ otherwise you have no solutions. Suppose here these numbers are all $>0$

Than you can fix $d>0$ and check that these are solutions:

$a=\frac{n_1n_3}{n_2d}$, 
$b=\frac{n_2d}{n_3}$,
$c=\frac{n_3}{d}$

Comment: If all $n_1,n_2,n_3,n_4$ are positive, find the positive solutions by taking logarithms : $$\log a+\log b=\log n_1\\\cdots\\\log d+\log a=\log n_4$$ and apply Gaussian elimination or any other methods for solving *linear* systems. Otherwise, solve with $|n_1|,\ldots,|n_4|$ and then change the signs as necessary.

Comment: Usually by $n_i$ a positive integer is denoted. Then, say, $ab=6$ is considered over the integers, I suppose. So we have $a=2$ or $a=3$, up to sign.

Answer (score 1):

Generally there are either infinite number of solutions or no solutions. If $n_1n_3\ne n_2n_4$, There will be definitely no solution. For the other case, if none of the products are zero, there will be infinite number of solutions: $b=n_1/a,c=n_2a/n_1,d=n_4/a$. Of course, if some of the products were zero, there will also be an infinite number of solutions. But this is left as exercise.